# Internet sharing on Mac to use /etc/host rules

Tags: macos, localhost, dnsmasq

I have added two new rules to my /etc/host file. I tested them locally via my browser and they work. What I am trying to do is have any device that connects to my mac wifi module via internet sharing, to use the same rules set in my /etc/host file.

Comment: This is a usage / networking question, not a software development question, *even* if it arises as something you need to accomplish during an unspecified development project.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way via DNSMasq. Just have to make sure to start dnsmasq prior to internet sharing as it appears MacOS automatically creates its own DNS on the same port.